# Rename folders and files inside them

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

My folder structure looks like this:

```
D:
| - ADC
   | - LH
        | - LH_A-DXB
            | - LH_A-DXB_MKI-I
                | - LH_A-DXB_MKI-I_AE
                    | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_LH_A-DXB_MKI-I_AE.xml
                ....
                | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_LH_A-DXB_MKI-I
            ...
            | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_LH_A-DXB.xml
        | - LH_A-FRA
        ...
        | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_LH.xml
   | - LX
   ...
   | - OS
   ...
   | - SN
   | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC.xml
```

There are more than 800 folders and 800 files.
I need to rename the names `"PointOfSale"` by adding `"ADC_"` to everyone except the folder `"ADC"` (all children)

Example
each directory `.. \ [posCode] .. rename to .. \ ADC_ [posCode];`

each file `.. \ [posCode] \ PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ [posCode] .xml .. in .. \ ADC_ [posCode] \ PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC_ [posCode] .xml`

Example output:

```
D:
| - ADC
   | - LH
        | - ADC_LH_A-DXB
            | - ADC_LH_A-DXB_MKI-I
                | - ADC_LH_A-DXB_MKI-I_AE
                    | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC_LH_A-DXB_MKI-I_AE.xml
                ....
                | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC_LH_A-DXB_MKI-I
            ...
            | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC_LH_A-DXB.xml
        | - ADC_LH_A-FRA
        ...
        | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC_LH.xml
   | - LX
   ...
   | - OS
   ...
   | - SN
   | - PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC.xml
```

My code:

```
public class Parser {
    public List<File> getFileList(String directoryPath, ArrayList<File> files) {
        File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        File[] filesList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : filesList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
            if (file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")).equals(".xml")) {
                files.add(file);
            }
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            this.getFileList(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
        }
    }
    return files;
}

public void renameFiles(List<File> files) {
    if (files.size() > 0) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (!(file.getName().equals("PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC.xml"))) {
                System.out.println(file);
                String newName = file.getAbsolutePath().replace("PointOfSaleManageSvRQ", "PointOfSaleManageSvRQ_ADC");
                System.out.println(newName);
                boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(newName));
                if (success) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully renamed!");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

public List<File> getDirectoryList(String directoryPath, ArrayList<File> directories) {
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File[] filesList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File item : filesList) {
        if (item.isDirectory()) {
            directories.add(item);
            System.out.println("File" + item.getAbsolutePath());
            this.getDirectoryList(item.getAbsolutePath(), directories);
        }
    }
    return directories;
}

public void renameDirectories(List<File> directories) {
    if (directories.size() > 0) {
        for (File item : directories) {
            if (!((item.getName().equals("LH")) || (item.getName().equals("LX")) || (item.getName().equals("OS")) || (item.getName().equals("SN")))) {
                System.out.println(item);
                String newFolder = item.getAbsolutePath().replace(item.getName(), item.getName());
                System.out.println(newFolder);
                boolean success = item.renameTo(new File(newFolder));
                if (success) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully renamed!");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Everything works, but the folders that are in "LH", "LX", "OS", "SN" are renamed.

Where is the mistake?
And please give tips on optimizing the code.